# binomial theorem: find coef. xy

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Given:

$$
\left(x-\dfrac{1}{2y}\right)^8\left(x+\dfrac{1}{2y}\right)^4
$$

Using binomial theorem, what is the coefficient of xy in the expansion?

I've tried to do it but I couldn't. Could you please help me with it?

Comment: I converted the expression to $\LaTeX$. Is this what you meant?

Comment: yes is it, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you multiply
$$
\left( \sum_{k=0}^8 \binom{8}{k}{x^k {\left(-1 \over 2y\right)}^{8-k} }\right)
\left( \sum_{l=0}^4 \binom{4}{k}{x^l {\left(1 \over 2y\right)}^{4-l} }\right)
$$
you will **never** get $xy$

Answer (score 3):

$y$ is in denominator in both the terms $\left(x-\dfrac{1}{2y}\right)^8$ and $\left(x+\dfrac{1}{2y}\right)^4$ and powers are $4$ and $8$(both positive). So, how do you expect to get $xy$.

Simply, the coefficient of $xy$ is $0$